# Spring SecurityFilterChain leads to blank page

Tags: spring-security, security-filter

I'm testing spring security with the simplest maven project I can do:

- pom.xml
- src/main/java/oa/tests/securitytest/SecurityTest.java
- src/main/java/oa/tests/securitytest/SecurityConfig.java
- src/main/resources/application.properties
- src/main/resources/static/index.html
- src/main/resources/static/test.html

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html)
Now I have this behavior:

- With no SecurityFilterChain bean as defined in SecurityConfig.java:
  All my pages require authentication and as an authenticated user, I can see them fine.
- With SecurityFilterChain bean:
  I can see index.html without authentication, but test.html is an empty page and no authentication is required.

Can you please point out my mistake in the SecurityFilterChain bean?

I tried changing my auth2 server with these lines in application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=530421597466-qrujkh0hfnrgXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=WN4_yZ_fB5BZB5XXXXXXXXXX
```

But clearly, the error is in the SecurityFilterChain bean. I've tried several changes to this file, but I'm confused about what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>oa.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>securitytest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>securitytest</name>
    <description>Test for Spring security</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring.boot.mainclass>oa.tests.securitytest.SecurityTest</spring.boot.mainclass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SecurityTest.java:

```
package oa.tests.securitytest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SecurityTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
package oa.tests.securitytest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                .requestMatchers("/index.html", "/error").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .logout(l -> l
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                )
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.clientId=4e5e66b02640eeb2XXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.clientSecret=acefbb827cf0c635d1331e122ba912XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: You should remove your Github secret from this question and, as it is still going to be available from revisions history, change it on Github.

Comment: It is not complete: you can see it filled with "XXXXX", also with google credentials.
Thanks for the advice 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))` [you ask Spring Security to return `401 Unauthorized` to unauthorized requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authenticationentrypoint) (instead of the default which is `302 Redirect to login`). This is not in the tutorial you linked and is most probably the cause for your current problem when trying to access your protected page.

I suggest that you have a look at my [OAuth2 essentials and tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2)...

Comment: I'm in debt with you, ch4mp. I'll read your tutorial 